# Pin 0 (62) you are trying to use is not supporting interrupts

Tags: arduino-mega, interrupt

Using `RCLib` ([github](https://github.com/jantje/ArduinoLibraries/tree/master/RCLib)) I'm getting this error. The trick is that the RCLib [example](https://github.com/jantje/ArduinoLibraries/blob/master/RCLib/Examples/Maga6ChanelsA8_A13/Maga6ChanelsA8_A13.ino) works on it's own but does not work in my program ([github](https://github.com/jacksonkr/SwatBotSpine)).

**Serial Output "Error"**

```
Pin 0 (62) you are trying to use is not supporting interrupts
Pin 1 (63) you are trying to use is not supporting interrupts
Pin 2 (64) you are trying to use is not supporting interrupts
Pin 3 (65) you are trying to use is not supporting interrupts
Pin 4 (66) you are trying to use is not supporting interrupts
Pin 5 (67) you are trying to use is not supporting interrupts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite right. Those pins aren't interrupt pins. What you want to do is make it use *PinChange interrupt* pins instead.

This can (by the look of things) be done by including the PinChangeInt.h library before including the RCLib library.

Comment: Does that make the Arduino use software interrupts instead of hardware interrupts?

Comment: No. That makes a different kind of hardware interrupt available to that library.

Comment: Hmm, well I have NO idea how you came to this conclusion and the quickness at which you did it is disorienting. I'm sure much of it chalks up to experience but can I bother you to open my mind to your troubleshooting technique(s) ?

Comment: Simple: I looked at the source code for RCLib.h and found the bit where the error message is. Then I saw that it's wrapped in a test to see if PinChangeInt_h was defined (which is done by the PinChangeInt.h library) and that by including that library it will change the behaviour accordingly.